# re-creating a button hover effect from a website

Tags: css, button, hover, css-animations

I want to a button with the same hover effect as in [foxmovies.com](http://www.foxmovies.com/)
[these are the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBujN.png).

I didn't manage to find an example online, with the arrow moving effect. 
any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Members are looking to help you. However, you'll get further if you try first and then show us what you've tried. Show us what you've tried. Get creative :)

Comment: ok thanks, your'e right

Answer (score 0):

Created the base hover effect, tweak it for extra efffect

```css
.btn span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 4px;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 24px;
  background-color: #B08A43;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #B08A43 50%, #CA9E4D 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #B08A43 50%, #CA9E4D 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #B08A43 50%, #CA9E4D 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #B08A43 50%, #CA9E4D 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: background-position 100ms ease;
  transition: background-position 100ms ease;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}
span.arrow {
  background-color: #B08A43;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #B08A43 50%, #CA9E4D 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #B08A43 50%, #CA9E4D 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #B08A43 50%, #CA9E4D 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #B08A43 50%, #CA9E4D 50%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  float: none;
  line-height: 48px;
  background-color: #B08A43;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: background-position 200ms ease;
  transition: background-position 200ms ease;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}
a:hover span {
  background-position: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn">
  <span>Watch the Trailer</span>
  <span class="arrow">></span>
</a>
```